# How Does Spring MVC handle responses

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httpresponse, spring-webflow, keep-alive

I use Spring MVC and webflow.  There are time where I am obliged to write to the response object directly.  Specifically I have a keep-alive class that continuously sends an empty response back to the browser while the server does some slow running operations, and I write to the response directly.  This class is used in a part of my application that is built on webflow and also in parts of our site that just use spring MVC.  When we introduced webflow, our keep-alive class broke.  Apparently when webflow sends a response to the browser it calls:

`response.getWriter().print(stuff)`

But when the spring MVC part of our app sends responses to the browser, it uses

```
response.getOutputStream().print(stuff)
```

Response is an HttpServletResponse object. You cannot call getWriter and getOutputStream on the same response.  An illegal state exception will be thrown.

How can I override this behavior in either webflow or spring mvc so that they handle responses the same way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a servlet filter.  A filter can intercept all output and rewrite in another way.
A good example of this is with the jsonp filter:
http://jpgmr.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/tutorial-implementing-a-servlet-filter-for-jsonp-callback-with-springs-delegatingfilterproxy/

Comment: this will probably help me achieve my goal, but I was hoping to gain a better understanding as to what was causing this problem, and thus gaining a better understanding of spring.